# Probability of drawn cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Determine the probability that in a group of $7$ randomly drawn cards from well
mixed deck of $52$ cards will be exactly $2$ cards with a picture and exactly $4$ red cards (hearts or diamonds)

I don't know how to start I have trouble with reasoning in this case

Comment: *Exactly* $2$ cards with a picture or *at least* $2$ cards with a picture? Same question for the reds.

Comment: @drhab exactly 2 cards with picture and exactly 4 red cards

Comment: Are aces counted as picture cards?

Comment: @Arthur let's say no but even if you count aces as pictures it's ok I think cause the problem is in reasoning not in numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following events are disjoint and their union is the event you mention:

- $2$ red cards with a picture, $2$ red cards without a picture, $3$ black cards without a picture.
- $1$ red card with a picture, $1$ black card with a picture, $3$ red cards without a picture, $2$ black cards without a picture.
- $2$ black cards with a picture, $4$ red cards without a picture, $1$ black card without a picture.

So determine the corresponding probabilities and summate. Can you do that?

---

**edit**:

$\begin{array}{cccccc}
 & RP & RP^{c} & BP & BP^{c}\\
 & 6 & 20 & 6 & 20 & total\\
\hline E_{1} & 2 & 2 & 0 & 3\\
E_{2} & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2\\
E_{3} & 0 & 4 & 2 & 1\end{array}$

$$P(E_1)=\frac{\binom{6}2\binom{20}2\binom60\binom{20}3}{\binom{52}7}$$

Do you understand why?

Comment: I'm trying but I need more details for every event I don't know how to calculate probability for each event, what form to use?

Comment: I have edited to put you on trail.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much @drhab

Comment: Glad to help. Aside: is that you on the picture? Gorgeous! :-).

Comment: Yes it's me, thank you very much for compliments :-)